# Given two matrices to find one way to write a determinant

Tags: matrices

Given two matrices (2X2) with AB=BA,I was wondering if there is a way to decompose this expression $$ xA^2+yAB+zB^2$$

Comment: decompose to what?

Comment: In a product of factors

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

if $AB=BA$ then for every (real?) numbers $a,b,c,d$ one has
$$
(aA+bB)(cA+dB)=acA^2+(ad+bc)AB+bdB^2.
$$
Thus what you are asking is: given $x,y,z$ can I find $a,b,c,d$ such that
$$
ac=x,\quad y=ad+bc, \quad z=bd \quad?
$$
Can you?

Comment: I don't think I can... Well,I thought there might be some way to express the determinant of the expression.

Comment: @Urania: in general the determinant doesn't behave well under the sum of matrices.

Comment: Yes,I know but I want to prove an inequality and I thought maybe I could use the characteristic polynomial or some other way.But I don't know how to do it..